# Which of "and" or "or" should I use to join non-equality checks, and why?

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, multiple-conditions

This is a very simple dice roll program that keeps rolling two dice until it gets double sixes. So my while statement is structured as:

```
while DieOne != 6 and DieTwo != 6:
```

For some reason, the program ends as soon as `DieOne` gets a six. `DieTwo` is not considered at all.

But if I change the `and` to an `or` in the while statement, the program functions perfectly. This doesn't make sense to me.

```
import random
print('How many times before double 6s?')
num=0
DieOne = 0
DieTwo = 0

while DieOne != 6 or DieTwo != 6:
    num = num + 1
    DieOne = random.randint(1,6)
    DieTwo = random.randint(1,6)
    print(DieOne)
    print(DieTwo)
    print()
    if (DieOne == 6) and (DieTwo == 6):
        num = str(num)
        print('You got double 6s in ' + num + ' tries!')
        print()
        break
```

Comment: If `DieOne` is 6 then the statement `DieOne != 6 and DieTwo != 6` is false because it's not true the both die are not equal to six.

Comment: That makes sense to me, so it's unclear what you're asking. You want the loop to end when *both* checks are false, so or is the correct combination.

Comment: the problem is this. you want `NOT(die 1 is 6 AND die 2 is 6).` The equivalent condition becomes `die 1 is NOT 6 OR die 2 is NOT 6.` This is a logic problem that you'd need to work out. when you say "die 1 is not 6 AND die 2 is not 6", the condition will immediately fail the moment one of them become a 6, because AND needs to ensure BOTH conditions stay satisfied.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: ps. the way you have the code written though, you have a break statement to leave the loop. so to be honest a `while true` works just fine, you have a condition in place to leave the loop already.

Comment: I guess my brain is thinking in terms of an IF statement rather than WHILE. If condition A is false AND condition B is false then . . .  But WHILE is structured differently. WHILE condition A is false OR condition B is false. This is not intuitive for me.

Comment: no, dont mix your while or code syntax at all.youre getting the math behind it wrong because of the way "not" works. the bottom line is this: both if and while work when the condition in front of them is TRUE. not false. you should move the "negation" logic into the way conditional is being structured.

Comment: simplify: `while DieOne+DieTwo != 12:` ... or simply `while True:` together with your `break`

Comment: hey thats cheating. :P @PatrickArtner

Comment: @ParitoshSingh How is that "cheating," its coding, if it works it works.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh DeMorgan is the way to go and you explained it well ... but simpler is often ...simpler ;o) - the less I have to think about it the easer the next reviewer will have it  - see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/  number 3

Comment: haha yes indeed, agreed. cant resist the opportunity for a tongue in cheek remark though if it presents itself like that :P

Comment: I much appreciate the comments here. I can see my confusion now. I like the while DieOne + Die2 != 12 much better.

Answer (score 18):

TLDR at bottom.

First off, while loops run if the following condition is true, so

```
DieOne != 6 or DieTwo != 6:
```

must return true when simplified, for the while funtion to run

The *and* operator returns true if **both** conditions are true, so the while loop will only run when it is *True and True*.

So the following won't run if either of the dice rolled a 6 for example:

```
while DieOne != 6 and DieTwo != 6:
```

If DieOne rolled a 4 and DieTwo rolled a 6, the while loop won't run because DieOne != 6 is true, and DieTwo != 6 is false. I put this train of thought into code below.

```
while DieOne != 6 and DieTwo != 6:
while True and False:
while False: #So it won't run because it is false
```

The *or* operator works differently, the *or* operator returns true when **one** of the conditions is true, so the while loop will run when it is *True or True*, *True or False*, or _False or True.
So

```
while DieOne != 6 or DieTwo != 6:
```

will run if only either dice rolled a six. For example:

If DieOne rolled a 4 and DieTwo rolled a 6, the while loop will run because DieOne != 6 is true, and DieTwo != 6 is false. I put this train of thought into code below.

```
while DieOne != 6 or DieTwo != 6:
while True or False:
while True: #So it will run because it is true
```

**TLDR/Review:**

```
while True: #Will run
while False: #Won't run
```

And:

```
while True and True: #Will run
while True and False: #Won't run
while False and True: #Won't run
while False and False: #Won't run
```

Or:

```
while True or True: #Will run
while True or False: #Will run
while False or True: #Will run
while False or False: #Won't run
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `Not` instead of `!=`.

try this:

```
while not (DieOne == 6 or DieTwo == 6):
```

Comment: Good try, but this runs into the same problem as my original code. It works if you change the Or operator to And.

Answer (score 0):

```
while DieOne != 6:
   if DieTwo != 6:
      break
   num = num + 1
   DieOne = random.randint(1, 6)
   DieTwo = random.randint(1, 6)
   print(DieOne)
   print(DieTwo)
   print()
   if (DieOne == 6) and (DieTwo == 6):
      num = str(num)
      print('You got double 6s in ' + num + ' tries!')
      print()
      break
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Boil it down to a single condition, `both_6:bool`, based on multiple conditions:

```py
import random

num = 0
both_6 = False

​
while not both_6:
    num += 1

    DieOne = random.randint(1,6)
    DieTwo = random.randint(1,6)

    if (DieOne==6) and (DieTwo==6):
        both_6 = True
        print(f"\nIt took you {num} attempts to get double sixes!\n")


"""
It took you 25 attempts to get double sixes!
"""
```

It *feels* like multiple conditions is broken