# "or" & "and" in loop (while) structure

Tags: python

I was trying to make a simple program that asks for the sex of the user. And the only two inputs it accepts it is: "M" or "F".

Then:

```
sex = str(input('[ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

while sex != 'M' or sex != 'F':
     print('error')
     sex = str(input('try again [ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

print('It's done :)')
```

But it only works if i use the term "**and**" in the loop. It is not a big question but i really wanted to know why...

Comment: Because every possible value of `sex` will *always* "not equal" at least one of `'M'` or `'F'`...

Comment: Please, **do not** use Markdown in source code. Use code comments.

Comment: 'I need someone who's not X and simultaneously also not Y". Neither X nor Y can be both itself and not itself.

Comment: `sex` can only hold one value at a time, so it is always not equal to `M` or not equal to `F`. If it is `F` it is not equal to `M` and if it is `M` it is not equal to `F`. Or it could be equal to neither of those, of course. The reason it works with `and` is that `and` is the correct conjunction to use here.

Comment: PSA: Test for "inclusion in list" versus this type of coding. `if sex in sexes`.

Comment: (1) "Is `sex` different from `'M'`?" (2) "Is `sex` different from `'F'`?" (3) Is the answer to either 1 or 2 "yes"? ... The answer to question 3 is always "yes", right?

Comment: By the way, a better way to write this is `sex not in ('M', 'F')` which is a lot clearer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 'while' with two conditions: "and" or "or"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163163/python-while-with-two-conditions-and-or-or)

Answer (score 4):

For your `while` loop to break you need both conditions to be `False`, this would mean `sex` being both `M` and `F` at the same time.

This is never possible.

Corrected code:

```
sex = str(input('[ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

while sex != 'M' and sex != 'F':
    print('error')
    sex = str(input('try again [ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

print('It\'s done :)')
```

Or using [De Morgan's equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
sex = str(input('[ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

while not (sex == 'M' or sex == 'F'):
    print('error')
    sex = str(input('try again [ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

print('It\'s done :)')
```

Or the classical pythonic way:

```
sex = str(input('[ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

while sex not in {'F', 'M'}:
    print('error')
    sex = str(input('try again [ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip()

print('It\'s done :)')
```

Comment: For the pythonic way I most frequently see lists being used, not sets, and I would suggest doing that: a set has better *asymptotic* runtime, but it has a substantial constant overhead compared to a list, and is therefore no faster than lists for a small number of elements (indeed, it will be *slower*).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree that for two items a `tuple`/`list` is better, I just use sets out of habit and I don't think the difference here matters much (especially in a loop with user input) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's put 3 cases into a truth table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
sex  |  sex != 'M'  |  sex != 'F'  |           |  
     |       A      |       B      |   A or B  |  A and B
----------------------------------------------------------
X    |     True     |     True     |    True   |    True
M    |     False    |     True     |    True   |    False
F    |     True     |     False    |    True   |    False
----------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see from the table, **and** is clearly the correct choice, while **or** always returns True.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of code and at the same time make it more robust as follows:

```
while (sex := input('[ M / F ]: ')).upper().strip() not in 'MF':
    print('error\ntry again ', end='')
# sex variable could be used here
print('It\'s done :)')
```

By using *in* rather than *and* or the erroneous *or* condition you will have simplified the process. Note also that *input()* returns *str* so the call to *str()* is irrelevant. It will work but it's unnecessary